# Are there workarounds for when browser shortcut keys break for users with foreign language keyboards?

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts, localization

The shortcut to bring up the search interface in Trello is `/`, but a Trello user is reporting that the `/` key on his Swedish keyboard does not bring up search.

I've seen this issue with other web apps and non-English-US keyboards as well. Is there a workaround for users with foreign language keyboards to be able to use these kinds of keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** `/` works on my swedish keyboard now.

On a Swedish keyboard use the `'` (single quote) or `*` (asterisk) to toggle the search bar in Trello.

Answer (score 0):

On a Norwegian keyboard the search field is opened by the indent key

> ⇥  (tab)